# How to redirect with masking a domain with frame and preserve bootstrap responsiveness on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, redirect, responsiveness, url-masking

I have read numerous posts on the problems but have not found a solution yet... so here is my new post.

All my domains are hosted at GoDaddy.  The main url is helloguest.com.au.  I have setup heavenlyhyams.com.au to forward with masking to helloguest.com.au/Heavenly_Hyams, but the responsiveness on mobile is lost due to the frame.

It is important for me to mask the final url, so what is the best solution?

I saw a post that the same result can be achieved without masking but by adding a CNAME... but I don't understand how.  So please explain step by step if that is possible.

The second option I am currently trying is to control the frame code.  So for that I have setup heavenlyhyams.com as an add-on domain and add the same frame code in the index file.  There seems to be several way to add responsiveness to the frame, so I would appreciate if someone could help me here.